# Does C# have a ContainsAny() method for a dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a dictionary where the Key is an Id and the value is a string

I now have a List of person objects where each person has a CarIds property that is an

```
IEnumerable<int>
```

I want to basically filter the list of objects to only include items where one of the properties is included in the dict.

For example.  something like this:

```
var dictionary = GetDict();

var people = GetPeople();

 people = people.Where(r => dictionary.ContainsAny(r.CarIds)).ToList();
```

Does something like this exist where I can do something similar to ContainsKey() but check for any in a list of ints ?

Comment: Pedantic: C# doesn't even have dictionaries, much less methods like ContainsAny. .NET has dictionaries and might have had such a method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can try this for lists:

```
people = people.Where(r => list.Intersect(r.CarIds).Count() != 0).ToList();
```

For dictionaries, you can use this:

```
people = people.Where(r => r.CarIds.Any(n => dictionary.ContainsKey(n))).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks.  one tweak as it looks like i need list.Keys.Intersect given its a dictionary

Comment: @leora Try the update, it should work faster than the `Intersect`.

Comment: i don't follow your updated answer it seems to be returning bool but you are doing a != 0 check . .

Answer (score 6):

your best bet is probably to extend Dictionary (which probably ought to have a `ContainsAny()` or `ContainsAnyKey()`).

```
 public static bool ContainsAny<K, V>(
        this Dictionary<K, V> dict, IEnumerable<K> keys)
 {
     foreach(K key in keys)
         if(dict.ContainsKey(key)) return true;
     return false;
 }
```

and this can be linq'd as:

```
    public static bool ContainsAny<K, V>(
           this Dictionary<K, V> dict, IEnumerable<K> keys)
    {  return keys.Any(key => dict.ContainsKey(key));  }
```